# Show RDLC Report in Client PC WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

I have Develop a WPF (.NET Framework 4.7.2) using visual Studio 2019 . I have used RDLC Report. Reports works fine in development pc. but when I Run .exe in client PC Report not showing, it show error. 
Which software need to install in client pc for run RDLC report in Client PC

Comment: please share the error you are receiving

Comment: the invocation of the constructor on type microsoft reporting winforms reportviewer that matches the specified binding constraints threw an execption line number 15 and line position 14

Comment: Everything that's in your project's build bin - debug or release.  If either  Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms or WindowsFormsIntegration dlls are not delivered then this definitely isn't going to work.

Answer (score -1):

List to check

1. Make sure your all relevant services are running on client (Sql etc)
2. Check your build configurations for referencing assemblies mismatched between x64 and x86
3. you can check by adding this in your app.config
4. Make sure your client machine has relevant framework installed.

Comment: Point No. 3  <configuration> <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" /> </configuration>